# VSTS REST api returns xml when it should return json

Tags: c#, rest, azure-devops, httpwebrequest, azure-devops-rest-api

```
class RestClient
    { public string endPoint { get; set; }

        public RestClient(string e)
        {
            endPoint = e;
        }
        public string makeRequest()
        {
            string strResponse = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endPoint);
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Credentials = HeaderTool.nCred;
            request.Method = "GET";

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status code not ok");
                }
                //Process the response stream
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            strResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }//End of responseStream scope
            }

            return strResponse;
        }//End of response scope
    }
```

So I'm looking at my project's commits on TFS, with the suffix /commits?searchCriteria.includeWorkItems=true&api-version=4.1
which works
However, whatever I do, when I print the output in console, it is of XML. I've set the HttpWebRequest's Accept field to application/json, but it changes nothing
I even tried appending .json to the uri

I want this sort of output
{
    "commitId": "SHA",
    "author":{
        "name": "Bill Nye the Science Guy",
        "email": "gmail@gmail.com",
        "date": "2018"
    }
}
You get the just of it
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
First part of output:


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">






<html lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>

            Microsoft Team Foundation Server

</title><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" /><meta name="msapplication-config" content="none" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/tfs/favicon.ico"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an authentication error or a 404? Post the code you're using to call the REST API.

Comment: @DanielMann I've received those errors before. Output was different. Anyways the class I use is posted above

Comment: @Zealia Can you show the whole project you used in one drive?

Answer (score 0):

It's not returning XML. It's returning **HTML**. This is almost certainly because you're being redirected to a login page. You're being redirected to a login page because **you're not authenticating properly.**

I don't know the value of `HeaderTool.nCred`, but that's almost certainly not correct. You should use a personal authentication token or OAuth token for authenticating against VSTS.

There are [client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=vsts) you can use that handle proper authentication for you. I'd recommend implementing them over rolling your own.

You can also pass in a PAT to [authenticate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts#create-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate-access) via standard HTTP client libraries.

The relevant snippet for your scenario:

```
public static async void GetBuilds()
{
    try
    {
        var personalaccesstoken = "PATFROMWEB";

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                Convert.ToBase64String(
                    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                        string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                        "https://{account}.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/build-release/builds").Result)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that the PAT is being BASE64 encoded and being passed in via an Authentication header.

Comment: nCred is a NetworkCredential; NetworkCredential nCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain); - with this I was able to get a json back from https://{serverName&port}/tfs/{projectName}/_apis/build/builds/24144/workitems. However I cannot get this to work the http request that'd allow me to see what work items are associated with commit Ids